# Adding onClick attribute to Leaflet marker

Tags: typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to generate a list of points in Leaflet by looping through a `JSON file` and making each of them clickable in a way so I can get the active point into my react state.

**I found this nice example that worked perfectly:**

https://www.bekk.christmas/post/2020/13/a-hot-chocolate-map-with-react-leaflet-and-typescript
for displaying the points, but in addition, I would like to set a react state based on which one the user has clicked.

**When I try adding the `onClick` attribute:**

```
import { Popup, Marker } from "react-leaflet";
import { list } from "./HotChocolate";
...

  {list.map((item, index) => (
    <Marker
      icon={icon2}
      key={index}
      position={[item.lat, item.lon]}
      title={`${item.englishProductName} at ${item.vendor}`}
      onClick={() => {
        console.log(item);
        console.log("do something more");
      }}
    >
      <Popup>
        <strong>
          {item.englishProductName} at {item.vendor}
        </strong>
      </Popup>
    </Marker>
  ))}
```

**I get the following error:**

> Type '{ children: Element; icon: Icon<{ iconUrl: string; iconSize:
> [number, number]; }>; key: number; position: [number, number]; title:
> string; onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & MarkerProps & RefAttributes<Marker>'.
> Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> MarkerProps & RefAttributes<Marker>'

**The other files are:**

```
import { type HotChocolate } from "../../../leaflet";

export const list: HotChocolate[] = [
  {
    productName: "Varm belgisk sjokolade",
    englishProductName: "Belgian hot chocolate",
    vendor: "Steam kaffebar",
    location: "Jernbanetorget 1, Østbanehallen",
    lat: 59.91088362120013,
    lon: 10.752799203777597,
  },
  ...
];
```

**And the type definitions are:**

```
export interface HotChocolate {
  productName: string;
  englishProductName: string;
  vendor: string;
  location: string;
  lat: number;
  lon: number;
  description?: string;
  //onClick: () => void;
  //onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HtmlInputElement>;
}
```

I assume I should be adding an `onClick` type definition to the `leaflet.d.ts` file above, but I am struggling to get the type correct. Does anyone have any advice on how I could make the different points in the `HotChocolate` list clickable in a way to I can set a react state based on which item the user has clicked on?

Comment: I don't really understand why do you need to set the onClick event on the Marker component. Anyways, it seems that the on click property just doesn't exist on that component. So if that can help, try to use the onClick of the popup component insteaed. After all, each popup can be related to a single and unique Marker only.

Comment: Thank @MedOkl, I tried that as well, but I then got the following error then:


Type '{ children: ("" | Element | undefined)[]; onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PopupProps & RefAttributes<Popup>'.
  Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PopupProps & RefAttributes<Popup>'

Comment: Try using the `eventHandlers` prop instead of `onClick` - check out the example in the [react-leaflet docs](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components/#evented-behavior). Does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @strfx was pointing out in the comments, the solution was to add the **eventHandlers**
prop instead of onClick and then everything worked out perfectly.

Comment: You could leave a comment for them to post an answer that could be accepted.